# Size of Opensource Virtuoso DB or any particular graph

Tags: database, size, rdf, triplestore, virtuoso

I am conducting a study on comparison of storing RDF triples in different stores. With Virtuoso, is there any particular way to determine the size of the database? I tried with the .db file in db folder of opersource virtuoso but it seems the file either doesn't update or the data is being written some unknown place. It would be very good to determine size of individual Named Graphs. Any help in this case will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any meaningful way to do that. [Here's the explanation](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=1369128859.27972.1385.camel%40octo.iv.dev.null&forum_name=virtuoso-users) (quote follows):

> There's no way of doing that, because graphs are not stored apart from
>   each other. All RDF data reside in "shared" tables, namely
>   DB.DBA.RDF_QUAD for all quads (i.e., triples in graphs), DB.DBA.RDF_OBJ
>   for all distinct literals, DB.DBA.RDF_IRI for all distinct IRIs etc. If
>   a value appear in more than one triple it appears only once in the
>   "dictionary" table, so the footprint size should be "shared" between
>   "uses".
>
> Moreover, if all related triples are freed, the dictionary entry
>   remains, waiting for next reuse. Quads of DB.DBA.RDF_QUAD can be
>   counted, of course, but they're kept in heavily compressed form so the
>   actual disk size can not be calculated for a single graph --- each page
>   with data about that graph will probably contain data about other
>   graphs. To crown it all, there are remapped pages, they consume disk
>   space too.